# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sccm

I'm trying to return Windows update compliance data from SCCM using SQL, I've extracted the query from a built in SSRS report.

Instead of running a separate query for each @colname (Group of computers) I'm trying to combine into one query by declaring @colname as a table and inserting multiple values.

The error returned in SQL is:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My code:

```
DECLARE @title VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @colname TABLE (name VARCHAR(100));

SET @title = 'ADR | Workstation Software Updates 2017-12-14 09:01:38';

INSERT INTO @colname   
VALUES ('All Alpha Workstations'), ('All Beta Workstations'), ('All Delta Workstations');

SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) [Total Clients], li.title, coll.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ucs.status = 3 OR ucs.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Installed / Not Applicable',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ucs.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Required',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ucs.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Unknown',
    ROUND((CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ucs.status = 3 OR ucs.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS float) / COUNT(*)) * 100, 2) AS 'Success %',
    ROUND((CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN ucs.status NOT IN ('3', '1') THEN '*' END) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(*)) * 100, 2) AS 'Not Success%'
FROM
    v_Update_ComplianceStatusAll UCS
INNER JOIN
    v_r_system sys ON ucs.resourceid = sys.resourceid
INNER JOIN 
    v_FullCollectionMembership fcm ON ucs.resourceid = fcm.resourceid
INNER JOIN
    v_collection coll ON coll.collectionid = fcm.collectionid
INNER JOIN
    v_AuthListInfo LI ON ucs.ci_id = li.ci_id
WHERE 
    li.title = @title 
    AND coll.name = (SELECT name FROM @colname) --and ucs.status=2
GROUP BY
    li.title, coll.name
ORDER BY
    1
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The error msg is clear, your `(select name from @collname)` return more than 1 value.

Comment: It's clear it's returning more than 1 value, yes. But I needed help with how to deal with multiple values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The subquery `select name from @collname` returns more than one value, this is why you can't use `=`.

Use `IN` predicate instead of `=`:

```
where li.title=@title and coll.name in (select name from @collname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a Table variable for this? There's no need (Table Variables are always expected to return 1 row, unless you're using 2017 where it's 100). That *can* have significant implications on your query's performance.

Just do:

```
and coll.name IN ('All Alpha Workstations','All Beta Workstations','All Delta Workstations')
```