# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery ( greater than case ) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know what's the best solution to prevent this error in case of greater than operator :
As mentioned in this question [Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938931/subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-this-is-not-permitted-when-the-subquery)
, the solution in the case of `=` is to replace the equals operator to `In` and the problem will be fixed. but what about the case when I have `>` greater operator.

What can I do in this case?

What can replace the `>` operator to solve this issue?

```
select userId 
from Users,table o where
Users.isActive=1 and o.UserId = Users.UserId
group by UserId 
having o.HourStart > (select Hour 
                      from Hours h, table b where b.HoursId = Hours.HoursId
                      group by Hour)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want the query to do.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It's as simple as making sure that `select Hour from Hours h, Users group by Hour` only returns one result. A number of ways to handle that but that's most likely not going to return the result you expect. What exactly do you want to select? Show some input and expected output.

Comment: That subquery is pretty pointless. It will *duplicate* the `Hour` value for every `User` row and then *deduplicate* it with `Group By`. It's an expensive way to execute `select distinct Hour from Hours`. Unless `Hours` contains a single value `Hour` value though, this will return multiple values. Which of them should the server compare with `HourStart` ? The fist? Last? The middle one? A random one?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you trying to compare? This isn't something that can be fixed by replacing one operator with another

Comment: I will modify the query

Comment: In this context what is `>` supposed to mean, greater than any or greater than all?

Comment: I mean greater than all , all rows selected

Comment: Try changing your subquery to select the MAX value of Hour from the joined tables.

Comment: but I need the condition `o.HourStart > (select Hour from Hours h,...)` , I need to use greater operator from this field to all rows

Comment: @abdou31 - like I said, show some inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a set-based `ALL` and `ANY` operator, which compares a value to all of a set.**

**Notes:**

- Use proper join syntax, not commas, which were deprecated nearly 30 years ago
- You must put the filter in a `where` not a `having` because it is not part of the aggregation (it's also normally more efficient this way)
- `group by` is unnecessary in an `exists`-type subquery unless it also comes with a `having` inside the subquery

```sql
select u.userId 
from Users u
join table o on o.UserId = u.UserId
where u.isActive=1
  and o.HourStart > ALL (
                      select Hour 
                      from Hours h
                      join table b on b.HoursId = h.HoursId)
group by u.UserId
```

**But most people find it highly confusing.**

It is often easier to express these as an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, this means you need to flip the `>` to `<=`:

```sql
select u.userId 
from Users u
join table o on o.UserId = u.UserId
where Users.isActive=1
  and not exists (select 1
                      from Hours h
                      join table b on b.HoursId = h.HoursId
                      where h.Hour <= o.HourStart)
group by u.UserId
```

[See more on this by Brad Schulz](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/08/all-any-and-some-three-stooges.html)

Comment: I didn't have tested it yet but I think it will work.